# SQLAlchemy: Re-saving model's unique field after trying to save non-unique value

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

In my SQLAlchemy app I have the following model:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))

class MyModel(declarative_base()):
    # ...
    label = Column(String(20), unique=True)

    def save(self, force=False):
        DBSession.add(self)
        if force:
            DBSession.flush()
```

Later in code for every new `MyModel` objects I want to generate `label` randomly, and just regenerate it if the generated value is already exist in DB.
I'm trying to do the following:

```
# my_model is an object of MyModel
while True:
    my_model.label = generate_label()
    try:
        my_model.save(force=True)
    except IntegrityError:
        # label is not unique - will do one more iteration
        # (*)
        pass
    else:
        # my_model saved successfully - exit the loop
        break
```

but get this error in case when first generated `label` is not unique and `save()` called on the second (or later) iteration:

```
 InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (IntegrityError) column url_label is not unique...
```

When I add `DBSession.rollback()` in the position (*) I get this:

```
 ResourceClosedError: The transaction is closed
```

What should I do to handle this situation correctly?
Thanks

Comment: You should assign the return value of `declarative_base()` to a variable. Otherwise you'll experience problems when creating more than one model as you might have different base classes for them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `session` object rolls back essentially you have to create a new session and refresh your models before you can start again. And if you are use `zope.sqlalchemy` you should be using `transaction.commit()` and `transaction.abort()` to control things. So your loop would look something like this:

```
# you'll also need this import after your zope.sqlalchemy import statement
import transaction

while True:
    my_model.label = generate_label()
    try:
        transaction.commit()
    except IntegrityError:
        # need to use zope.sqlalchemy to clean things up
        transaction.abort()
        # recreate the session and re-add your object
        session = DBSession()
        session.add(my_model)
    else:
        break
```

I've pulled the use of the session object out of the object's `save` method here. I am not entirely sure how the `ScopedSession` refreshes itself when being used at the class level as you have done. Personally, I think embedding `SqlAlchemy` stuff inside your models doesn't really work well with SqlAlchemy's `unit of work` approach to things any how.

If your label object really is a generated and unique value, then I would agree with `TokenMacGuy` and just use a `uuid` value.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ScopedSession uses a thread local storage model;  the session is invalidated explicitly (via `ScopedSession.reset()`), but that's usually taken care of by the framework that gives you the session, at the time you return control of the request to the framework.  It's a convenience when the framework helps out, but a real headache if you can't use this sort of thread model.  Unless you're designing a mulithreaded framework, scopedesssion is not what you want.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy - I think what you're getting at is that the ScopedSession is essentially a global object on the thread, so explicitly cleaning it up at the end of the request cycle (btw it is `ScopedSession.remove()` in 0.6/7) becomes an extra concern.

Comment: Right; if you have one thread per unit of work, then ScopedSession *might* simplify things for components that can't easily couple in any other way; but in many cases it's either quite possible to inject a session by means other than a global TLS container, or the thread per uow is just not possible, and ScopedSession won't help you at all.  This seems to be a common point of confusion for beginners; the scoped session makes the UOW somewhat magical, and the application becomes hard to debug when the framework doesn't manage the session in a way that lines up with the developers' expectation

Answer (score 2):

Databases don't have a consistent way of telling you *why* a transaction failed, in a form that is accessible to automation.  You can't generally try the transaction, and then retry because it failed *for some particular reason*.

If you know of a condition that you want to work around (like a unique constraint), what you have to do is check the constraint yourself.  In sqlalchemy, that's going to look something like this:

```
# Find a unique label
label = generate_label()
while DBsession.query(
        sqlalchemy.exists(sqlalchemy.orm.Query(Model)
                  .filter(Model.lable == label)
                  .statement)).scalar():
    label = generate_label()

# add that label to the model
my_model.label = label
DBSession.add(my_model)
DBSession.flush()
```

---

edit:  Another way to answer this is that you shouldn't automatically retry the transaction; You could instead return an HTTP status code of `307 Temporary Redirect` (with some salt in the Redirected URL) so that the transaction really is started fresh.

Comment: Yes, I thought about to check the constraint myself, but the problem is that there's no guarantee that the same value I've just generated and will going to store in DB will not appear in that DB between the moments of generating and storing. I didn't ask, how to know why transaction failed, I'm asking how to "repair" session in the correct way.

Comment: You should consider using an atomic sequence or globally unique key;  Most databases support some sort of sequence (For example, MySQL has AUTOINCREMENT).  If that isn't a sensible option for you, you can use a an ID generated by the `uuid` module for high probability of a unique id.

Comment: Thanks, will take a look on `uuid` module

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem in my webapp written in Pyramid framework. I found a bit different solution for that problem.

```
while True:
    try:
        my_model.label = generate_label()
        DBSession.flush()
        break
    except IntegrityError:
        # Rollback will recreate session:
        DBSession.rollback()
        # if my_model was in db it must be merged:
        my_model = DBSession.merge(my_model)
```

The merge part is crucial if the my_model was stored before. Without merge session would be empty so flush would not take any action.

Comment: Just a note: if you have a Pyramid app that uses pyramid_tm it's better to use transaction.abort() instead of DBSession.rollback()